# Why I get the 'NameError: free variable '???' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope'?

Tags: python, nameerror

I was writing a simple python code the other day using [3D-Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/) (v4.11) and Python (v3.6.7) on Windows 10.

Source code below:

```py
def RunCLI(self, module, params, onCompletedHandler):
    cliNode = slicer.cli.run(module, None, params)

    mask = cliNode.Cancelled | cliNode.Completed

    completed = False

    def OnStatusModified(caller, event):
        nonlocal completed

        if completed: return # Error

        status = cliNode.GetStatus() # Gives the same error for 'cliNode' if I comment the previuos line

        if status & mask != 0:
            completed = True
            onCompletedHandler()

    cliNode.AddObserver('ModifiedEvent', OnStatusModified)
    OnStatusModified(None, None)
```

It occasionally gives me the error:

> 'NameError: free variable 'completed' referenced before assignment in
>   enclosing scope'.

I have no clue why it happens and why sometimes it passes and sometimes it fails.

I'm not sure what is the internal implementation of `cliNode` (I don't think it matters) but I guess `cliNode` runs an executable in another thread and signals the status changes through 'ModifiedEvent'.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: try to pass the completed as a param to function OnStatusModified and remove it from there ` nonlocal completed`

Comment: @Bit I can't change the `OnStatusModified` signature.